# ASP NET Core SignalR OnDisconnectedAsync not firing with hub [Authorized]

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

.net core 2.1

Hub code:

```
[Authorize]    
public class OnlineHub : Hub
{
public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    int userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    var b = Context.ConnectionId;

    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);

}
```

Client code:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
        let token = "token";
        const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("https://localhost:44343/online", { accessTokenFactory: () => token })
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
            .build();

    connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
    });
```

Without [Authorize] all works fine, except Context.UserIdentifier in OnConnectedAsync, and it's explainable, but... with [Authorize] attribute on Hub class, OnConnectedAsync start working and OnDisconnected not fires at all, including 30sec timeout (by default).

Any ideas?

Comment: `OnConnectedAsync start working and OnDisconnected not fires at all` are there any error in browser console tab?

Comment: My case about event when user closed browser (or tab)

Comment: How did you solve this and what was the problem ?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a debugger attached and close the client by closing the browser tab, then you'll never observe `OnDisconnectedAsync` being fired. This is because SignalR check if a debugger is attached and don't trigger certain timeouts in order to making debugging easier. If you close by calling stop on the client then you should see `OnDisconnectedAsync` called.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtSecurityKey"]))
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

This should trigger OnDisconnectedAsync in SignalR Hub

Comment: Please provide an explanation on why this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

for blazor implement this code

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable
```

and paste this func. to code

```cs
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if (hubConnection is not null)
    {
        await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be very old issue, but i will add some experience about troubleshooting, maybe it'll help someone once. After investigating, why signalR javascript client is not causing `OnDisconnectedAsync` when using `Authorize` attribute and HTTP connection for messaging, i found that the DELETE method it sends to server is blocked by CORS policy. So you can look to request responses, and if request is blocked as restricted by CORS, highly likely you need to allow `DELETE` (and `OPTIONS` as well) method to your CORS policy.